# Is The Power Object Functor Faithful?

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

> In an elementary topos, can we conclude that the power object functor $P:\mathcal{E}\to\mathcal{E}^\text{op}$ is faithful, i.e. if $Pf=Pg:PY\to PX$ then $f=g:X\to Y$?

#### Scroll down for (incomplete) textbook proof!

If $f\neq g$ then the equalizer of $f$ and $g$ must be different from $X$, but I don't see directly how that would help.

My idea was the following:

We can construct the singleton map $\{\cdot\}_Y:Y\to PY$.  Then I believe that we can construct $\ulcorner x\in Pf(\{y\})\urcorner$ as a subobject of $X\times Y$ hence we have a map $f':X\to PY$ constructed from $Pf$.  For this map, the subobject $\ulcorner f'(x)\text{ is singleton}\urcorner$ should be equal to $X$ (but I don't know how to prove it).  Now I wonder if this suffices, i.e. when we have $f,g:X\to Y$ with $\ulcorner f(x)\in f'(x)\urcorner$ and $\ulcorner g(x)\in f'(x)\urcorner$ both equal to $X$ (i.e. true on all of $X$), would $f=g$ follow from here?

Or in other words, given a map $f':X\to PY$, can we construct $f'':X'\to Y$, where $X'$ is the subobject $\ulcorner f'(x)\text{ is singleton}\urcorner$, with the property $\ulcorner f''(x)\in f(x)\urcorner$, something like choice for singletons?

[EDIT] I Found a proof in Sheaves In Geometry And Logic:

> [image]
> [image]

But there is still some argument left out.  Overall, it seems not too far from my own thoughts.  But I still fail to put everything together.

Comment: @Shaun I don't understand your edit, this was not a question from a book or some other source, I just wondered about it...  Should I still format it as a blockquote?

Comment: Users often highlight the question using the block quote feature. It makes it quicker for others to see what's going on. Also, it needed paragraphing.

Comment: I see, thanks!  I used blockquote only when actually quoting...  But yeah, it makes sense.

Comment: Yoneda's lemma is tremendously helpful here.

Comment: If $h:Z\to X$ is the equaliser of $f,g$, then it suffices to show an equality of classifying arrows $\chi_Z=\chi_X$, and $\chi_Z$ can be represented as an arrow $\ast\to P(X)$. I was not able to progress further with this perspective

Comment: Another possible approach: if $P(f) = P(g)$, then $P^2(f) = P^2(g)$, and you have a commutative diagram with top $f, g : X \to Y$ and bottom $P^2(f) = P^2(g) : P^2(X) \to P^2(Y)$.  And then, using the fact that $Y \to P^2(Y)$ is monic, you can conclude $f = g$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler How do we see $Y\to P^2(Y)$ is monic?

Comment: @Trebor I don't see it yet, when I try to set the presheaf $F$ from the Yoneda lemma to $c\mapsto \text{Hom}(G(*), G(c))$ for some functor $G$ (which I want to prove faithful), I end up with needing to show that the trivial map from $\text{Hom}(c, c')$ to $\text{Nat}(\text{Hom}(*,c),\text{Hom}(G(*),G(c')))$ is injective, which seems to just circle back to $G$ being faithful?

Comment: @FShrike hmm, is $\cap_Y:P^2(Y)\to P(Y)$ a map?  Can we maybe use it to show $\cap_Y\eta_Y:Y\to P(Y)$ is equal to the singleton map $\{\}_Y$, which is monic?  (I think I saw the proof of the last statement somewhere...)

Comment: @FShrike For example, as a rough idea (to be translated via the machinery of the internal language): if you use $P(Y) \simeq \Omega^Y$, then the map is the interpretation of $\lambda (y : Y) (S : \Omega^Y) . S y$.  If $y, y' \in \operatorname{Hom}(U, Y)$ give the same element of $P^2(Y)$, then applying it to $\lambda (z : Y) . y = z$ will give $(y = y) = (y = y')$.

Comment: An interesting thing is that this is implied by, and is probably equivalent to, "$\eta_Y$ is the equaliser of $PP^{\mathsf{op}}(\eta_Y),\eta_{PP^{\mathsf{op}}(Y)}$"

Comment: @DanielSchepler Ah, I don't know about that internal language stuff.

Comment: I have no idea if this is true of every topos, but if $fx=gx$ for all $x:\ast\to X$ implies $f=g$ then we can copy the easiest proof in Set and first show $fx=gx$ always holds

Comment: @FShrike On that last question, apply the hypothesis on $\operatorname{id}_X : X \to X$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler I don't see what you mean. $\mathrm{id}_X$ has domain $X$, not $\ast$. Here I use $\ast$ for the terminal object. (presuming $X$ is not terminal)

Comment: Aaah, I'm so sorry, the proof is right in the book I'm reading (SiGaL): https://postimg.cc/gallery/q4r6zJd

Comment: @FShrike The hypothesis needs to be for all test objects $*$ and all $x : * \to X$, $fx = gx$.  (This is exactly the standard interpretation of $\forall x : X, f x = g x$ being true in the internal language, for example.)  If you try it only with some fixed $*$, then for example $*$ could be $h_U$ for some proper open subset $U$ of a topological space...

Comment: But the proof is still leaving some argument as exercise to the reader...  I'll update my question.

Comment: Another possible approach to showing $\eta_Y : Y \to P^2 Y$ monic: from the self-adjunction, you get $\varepsilon P \circ P \eta = \operatorname{id}$, and after taking opposite categories into account, you get $P \eta_Y$ split epic.  If you can then prove $Pf$ epic implies $f$ monic, you would be done.  And in turn, to prove that, it would suffice to show $g$ epic implies $Pg$ monic, again using the naturality diagram of $\eta$.

Comment: What is the easiest argument for $g$ epic implies $Pg$ monic?

Comment: Whoops, I ended up with a circular argument for the approach of using $g$ epic implies $Pg$ monic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us look at the problem from the point of view of Yoneda's lemma.  Then $P(f) : P(Y) \to P(X)$ corresponds to a morphism of functors $\operatorname{Sub}({-} \times Y) \to \operatorname{Sub}({-} \times X)$, which takes a subobject of $U \times Y$ to the pullback along $\operatorname{id}_U \times f : U \times X \to U \times Y$, which is a subobject of $U\times X$.  Now, if we take the special case where $U = Y$ and the subobject is the diagonal $(\operatorname{id}_Y, \operatorname{id}_Y) : Y \hookrightarrow Y \times Y$, then it is straightforward to check that the pullback is the transpose of the graph of $f$, $(f, \operatorname{id}_X) : X \hookrightarrow Y \times X$.

Therefore, if $P(f) = P(g)$, then $(f, \operatorname{id}_X)$ and $(g, \operatorname{id}_X)$ must give the same subobject of $Y \times X$.  In other words, there is some $h : X \to X$ such that $(f, \operatorname{id}_X) \circ h = (g, \operatorname{id}_X)$.  However, composing with $\pi_2$, we see that we must have $h = \operatorname{id}_X$; and then composing with $\pi_1$ gives that $g = f \circ h = f$.

Answer (score 5):

This answer is probably not what you want, but I felt that it might still be interesting. Because every elementary topos supports constructive reasoning via its "internal language", it is enough to give a constructive proof of the set/type-theoretic naive element-based analog:

Let $x \in X$. By definition, we have $x \in (Pf)(\{f(x)\})$. By $Pf = Pg$, we also have $x \in (Pg)(\{f(x)\})$. By definition, this amounts to $g(x) \in \{f(x)\}$, so $f(x) = g(x)$.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is very interesting.  I just want to understand the fundamental properties before I move on to internal language, but maybe that's the wrong direction and I should start with internal language right away!  But I think internal language requires colimits, which, as far as I remember, are already quite difficult to construct, so I think you need to do some work before using the internal language anyway.

Comment: Actually, coproducts aren't that difficult to construct using the internal language (in a bootstrapping phase).  The basic idea: first, you can work your way up to defining $p \lor q$ as an interpretation of $\forall r : \Omega, (p\rightarrow r) \rightarrow ((q\rightarrow r) \rightarrow r)$.  That then allows you to define "unions" of subobjects straightforwardly.  And then, if you can construct $U$ with monic $f : X \to U, g : Y \to U$ such that the intersection of those subobjects is initial, then the union will be a coproduct of $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: One possible example of such a $U$: define $U := P(X) \times P(Y)$, with $f$ the interpretation of $x \mapsto (\{ x \}, \emptyset)$ and $g$ the interpretation of $y \mapsto (\emptyset, \{ y \})$.

Comment: And as for coequalizers, you can construct "the intersection of all equivalence relations on $Y$ containing the image of $(f, g)$" using the interpretation constructed so far, and then take the quotient of $Y$ by that equivalence relation (for example as an interpretation of the usual construction of the subobject of $P(Y)$ consisting of equivalence classes).

Comment: And for an initial object, first define $\bot \in \operatorname{Hom}(1, \Omega)$ as the interpretation of $\forall p : \Omega, p$; and then, construct the initial object as the interpretation of $\{ x : 1 \mid \bot \}$.