# $k:A\to 0$ implies $A\cong 0$

Tags: solution-verification, category-theory, limits-colimits, topos-theory

$
\def\aut{\text{Aut}}
\def\hom{\text{Hom}}
\def\id{\text{id}}
\def\true{\mathsf{true}}
\def\xra{\xrightarrow}
$In the [SiGaL](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-0927-0) book, they prove that in an elementary topos, every $k:A\to 0$ is an iso, but to me the argument is very involved and not so elucidating (note that the whole machinery of slice categories is not even contained in the screenshot):
[image]

I wonder if there is a more fundamental proof for such an important property?  As far as I understand, this property is also key for showing $X\times 0\cong 0$ and hence $P(0)\cong 1$.

First, I tried to show it in a more basic setting with only finite limits and colimits, but I think the property fails here. For a counterexample, consider the the category $C$ with objects $X,0,1$ such that $0$ is initial, $1$ is final, and additional arrows $x^*:X\to 0$ $x_i:X\to X$ for $i\in\mathbf{N}$ satisfying the equalities $x_0=\id_X$, $x_1=0_Xx^*$ and $x_ix_j=x_{i+j}$. I believe to have shown that $C$ has finite limits and colimits. For a cone $F:D\to C$ such that $X$ is not contained in the cone, the limit is $0$ and the colimit is $1$. Otherwise, the limit is $(X,\phi)$ such that for $d\in D_0$ with $F_0(d)=X$, $\phi(d)=x_i$ where $i$ is the smallest number such that $F_1(f)=x_i$ for some arrow $f$ in $D_1$ with codomain $d$. Dually, for the colimit we choose $\phi(d)=x_j$ where $j$ is the smallest number with the condition as above but domain instead of codomain.

I think it would also work with $i\in\{0,1\}$ and $x_ix_j=x_{\max(i,j)}$.

Clearly, $X$ and $0$ are not isomorphic here.  Also $X\times 0\cong X$ so it seems that we need indeed more machinery to show the original claim. I think I could manage to prove it without power objects though, just in a category $E$ with finite limits, colimits and a subobject classifier $(\Omega, \true:1\to\Omega)$.

We have the pullback square $(A \xra{\id_A} A \xra{\phi_A} \Omega, A \to 1 \xra{\true} \Omega)$ from the definition of a subobject classifier with the full subobject $A$. Further, for any map $f : A \to A$, we have the commuting square $(A \xra{f} A \xra{\phi_A} \Omega, A \to 1 \xra{\true} \Omega)$ (which can be checked by introducing the diagonal $0 \to 1$, the upper triangle commutes by all maps to $1$ being equal and the lower triangle is just the pullback square from above), which means that every $f$ is a map from the limiting cone to itself, but by the universal property of the limiting cones, such a map is unique. Hence we have $A \xra{k} 0 \to A$ must be equal to the identity and $k$ is an isomorphisms.

So I basically just want to check if my counterexample and the proof are correct?

Comment: The proof relies on the fact that an arrow $f : E\to B$ of a category $\cal C$ is a terminal object in ${\cal C}/B$ if and only if it is an isomorphism. All the proof is a detailed explanation of how to prove that in a topos, $A\to \varnothing$ is a terminal object in ${\cal C}/ \varnothing$.

Comment: True, but the proof uses both adjoints of the pullback functor, which is not a trivial construction, at least for the right adjoint.

Comment: Just as a comment, a proof using the internal language as in [this other thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4744352/61604) would be as follows: "Trivially, composing the unique map $! : \emptyset \to A$ with the given map $k : A \to \emptyset$ yields the identity on $\emptyset$. Regarding the reverse composition $! \circ k$, let $x \in A$ be arbitrary. We want to show $(! \circ k)(x) = x$. We have $k(x) \in \emptyset$, so $\bot$, from which everything follows."

Comment: Of course, as part of constructing the interpretation of the internal language in the first place, at some point you need to give an interpretation of $x : 0 \vdash \bot \textrm{~true}$ (or something leading to that), and that interpretation will probably be something pretty closely related to this fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\require{AMScd}$I'm not really sure you've defined all possible compositions in your $C$ but it looks fine. Your proof is definitely wrong since it is just saying:

> For any $A$, there is exactly one map $f:A\to A$

This is extremely false, for example, in the topos of sets. You've misplaced the uniqueness in a pullback; there is a unique arrow $g:A\to A$ with $1_A\circ g=f$ and $A\to 1=A\overset{g}{\to}A\to1$. This is obviously true, $g=f$ is forced, but it is *not* saying that there is a unique arrow $g:A\to A$ full stop. You also don't need to bother with "$0\to1$", I didn't understand that point; for any $f:A\to A$, it is true that: $$\begin{CD}A@>!>>1\\@VfVV@VV\mathrm{true}V\\A@>>\phi_A>\Omega\end{CD}$$Commutes. That's because $\phi_A=\mathrm{true}\,\circ\,!$ and $!\,\circ f=\,!$. Essentially, for $\phi_A$ the pullback condition is completely trivial; it is just the statement $\phi_A=\mathrm{true}\,\circ\,!$. For general subobjects $\iota:B\hookrightarrow A$, we have that $\iota$ is the equaliser of $\phi_B$ and $\mathrm{true}\,\circ\,!$.

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot for pointing out my mistake.  Would you say power objects are necessary to prove this lemma?  I'm currently thinking about expanding my counterexample so that it contains power objects as well...

Comment: @fweth Uhm, sorry to say I'm not really sure. I don't actually know any topos theory, I've only been able to answer those of your questions that are accessible from "standard" (basic) category theory

Comment: @fweth Any category with finite limits and power objects is already a topos.  (It is then cartesian closed as well, and for example in the internal language the reason is essentially that finite limits and power objects are already enough to allow you to bootstrap up to an interpretation of $\{ f : P(X \times Y) \mid \forall x : X, \exists! y : Y, (x, y) \in f \}$ which serves as the exponential object $Y^X$.  And the subobject classifier becomes simply $\Omega := P(1)$.)

Comment: Interesting, but what about the other way around?  I think I found a counterexample with only finite limits, colimits and subobject classifiers but no power objects.  But if you say that's also not possible, that also subobject classifiers alone give rise to power objects, then I surely made a mistake.

Comment: @fweth That's not what they said. They said, power objects (+extra) allows one to construct exponential objects and a subobject classifier. They didn't say subobject classifiers (+extra) allows one to construct the exponential objects. I strongly doubt that's true